# Send a text(or string) to server and get a response

Tags: android, authentication, registration

I want to make a register/login app. I found a few examples but the most of this doesn't work for me. So I will do everything step by step. So first for the login I want to send the Server the username and the password of the user. So here is everything working, but as you can see I didn't send anything to the Server. So, where and how to send the "username" and "password" to the Server.

```
private void userLogin() {
    username = usernameField.getText().toString().trim();
    password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOGIN_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anything doesn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: your request is GET or POST?

Comment: You say you "found a few examples but the most of this doesn't work for me" -- What examples? Are they using PHP + MySQL or Node + MongoDB or (web Framework X) and (database Y)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following got if your request is GET request.

```
private void userLogin() {
    username = usernameField.getText().toString().trim();
    password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

  // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, LOGIN_URL+"?username="+username+"&password="+password, // here you have to add parameters of webservice
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Anything doesn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
 // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Plain-text password in the URL? Bad idea :)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes you are right. I also wont suggest to do like this but I am giving him solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send Data with a `GET` request HTTP body.

For that, you use a `POST` request.

Then, look at the other `StringRequest` constructors for the one that has more than 4 parameters for `(method, url, onSuccess, onFailure)`.

OR... I assume you are using a JSON REST API, so you need a `JSONObjectRequest`

Comment: In that case author has to change his server side code too :(

Comment: I think last comment is not for me.

Comment: @Amy Ooops. Multi-tasking :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not forbidden to use a body in a get request.

It is however a very bad idea. (more info here: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body))

This is why many http APIs do not allow you to do it.